# Retrieve the data form sql database to  datetimepicker and picturebox

Tags: c#

I have  datetimepicker and picturebox. I want to retrieve data in these controls using sql table.

for the texbox and combobox i m using this code but for above contriles this is not applicable..

```
while (dtRdr.Read())
            {
                txtdoctorid.Text = Convert.ToInt16(dtRdr[0]).ToString();
                txtdoctorname.Text = Convert.ToString(dtRdr[1]).ToString();
                txtfathername.Text = Convert.ToString(dtRdr[2]).ToString();
                cbospecialist.Text = Convert.ToString(dtRdr[4]).ToString();
                txtqualification.Text = Convert.ToString(dtRdr[5]).ToString(); 
            }
```

Plz give any answer for above controls.........

My table name is DOCTOR_DETAILS and cloumn name for date time picker date is DOB and data type is DateTime and column for image is PHOTO and datatype is image.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToString(dtRdr[1]).ToString()` you can remove the last `ToString()` as you already have a string with `Convert.ToString(`.

I suppose that:

- you have a date in column whose index will be called: `datetime_column_index`
- you have a bool in column whose index will be called: `is_male_female_column_index`
  when true -> Male, false -> Female.
- you have an Byte aray in column whose index will be called: `image_column_index`

then:

```
datetimepicker.DateTime = (DateTime)dtRdr[datetime_column_index];

radioButtonMale.Checked = (bool)dtRdr[is_male_column_index];
radioButtonFemale.Checked = !radioButtonMale.Checked;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((Byte[])dtRdr[image_column_index]);
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: In radio buttun there is error specified cost is not exist..and in picture box there is error unable to cost object of type 'system.string' to 'System.byte[]'

Comment: ok. In your question add a description of the source table: for each column: name, type. Specially for Male/female column and Image column, what information do you store there?